# WMI query on CMI_DataFile class yields "Invalid query" if it has "where condition1 AND condition2" (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

OK, here's what I'm doing distilled to only the System.Management calls:

Simple queries and Method invokes work over the same connection. This query won't. And the file exists on the remote machine. Clues?

```
myQuery = "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\Users\\someguy\\Documents\\' AND FileName = 'Default' AND Extension = 'rdp'";

options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = myUsername;
options.Password = myPassword;
options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:MYDOMAIN";
scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\REMOTEMACHINE\\root\\CIMV2", options);
scope.Connect();
searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(myQuery));
myResults = searcher.Get();
```

ManagementObjectSearcher.Get() gets me a ManagementException saying "Invalid query." A simpler query, like, say, "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter", works.

I tried to reduce the WHERE's to just one, i.e. "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'rdp'". It works, although obviously it doesn't get me what I want. (Before the edit I mistakenly thought it didn't work even then; see comments) I'm at the end of the rope here.

Comment: Can you double check the case for "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Extension = 'rdp'"  I have an idea as to why it is failing but it conflicts if that line is really failing and it is typed correctly.

Comment: The hell? It worked now! VSTS must have been caching old code or something. I did a "rebuild solution" just in case (my code resides in different assemblies within a solution).

It seems your theory has legs. So... what IS it?

Comment: Interesting. What woked, the query above with the single WHERE clause? What about the others?

Comment: Yes, whenever there's only one WHERE clause (no matter which field) it works; any "AND another clause" doesn't.

Comment: It screws up in different ways depending on which fields I'm searching. Let me try to summarize. All mentioned files or directories exist.<br><br>

C:\config.sys, C:\autoexec.bat, and any file in the root dir:

- Works with "where FileName = 'xxxx' and Extension = 'yyy'". If I include the Drive property in the search, query is accepted but sometimes - just sometimes - returns nothing. Including a Path in the search just gets me an "Invalid query" exception. Here's a text file with the results I got:<br><br>
http://users.vialink.com.br/jcastro/CIM_DataFile.txt<br><br>

Comment: It's maddening. When I look for config.sys, I can use both drive, filename, and extension in the search. When I look for a file in some guy's directory, it works when I use any TWO of those three fields.

Comment: Correct link: http://users.vialink.com.br/jcastro/CIM_DataFile.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am an idiot. Please don't beat me up.

Firstly, the query only works reliably if you pass ALL components of the file name in WHERE clauses.

Secondly, I had to double the backslashes in the path component, and I was doing it wrong. I did:

```
pathPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Whereas what I had to do was:

```
pathPath = pathPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

That's right. I worked under the assumption that String.Replace() changed the string in-line. Bad C# newbie. Bad.

Comment: Don't feel too frustrated.  I just made the *exact* same mistake.  :(