# Is there an API to convert from "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.UUUUUU-TZO" format to C# DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, type-conversion

Example: "20080807144334.410187-180" (-180 means GMT minus three hours. Rio de Janeiro in this case.)

That string format is returned when I query file creation/change/access times via WMI (that is not totally working; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927767/wmi-query-on-cmidatafile-class-yields-invalid-query-if-it-has-where-c)). I guess I could parse it the idiot way, extracting year, month etc. from the string positions. But I'd like not to reinvent the wheel. System.DateTime's constructors don't handle that format. Should I go on and do it the idiot way or is there something better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to give it the specific format to use when parsing.

However, I don't think you can get it to read your time zone in that format (though I can't actually figure out how to get it to read a time zone in any format).

The rest of it would look like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20080807144334.410187", "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and it doesn't reinvent the wheel, but by Zeus it's ugly. Behold:

retVal.CreationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(((string)queryObj["CreationDate"]).Substring(0,21), "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the DateTime.TryParseExact method.  It'll let you pass in your format that you're converting from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx