# wmi invalid query error

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wql

I am trying to get the size of this dsa file present in c:\windows\ntds\ directory.

I am getting error here, and I don’t know why. The error is “Invalid Query”.

I seems to get this error quite often when I work with different WMI classes.

**I don’t know why this error occur and how to resolve this?**

**Is there any error in below code, How to resolve this?**

**Why we will get this Invalid Query error, whats the source of it? Its inner exception will always be null?**

```
private int getDatabaseFileSize(string DSADatabaseFile, string machineName)
        {
            string scope = @"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2";
            string query = string.Format("Select FileSize from CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = '{0}'", DSADatabaseFile);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject mobj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Size : " + mobj["FileSize"]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you tell what was the value if `DSADatabaseFile` in the query?

Comment: I have all right, I am running this application under admin account.

Value for DSADatabaseFile is C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit and its size is 16MB.

I am getting exception as it will reach in keyword in foreach loop.

Comment: try this `C:\\Windows\\NTDS\\ntds.dit` or from the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/972232/1051198

Comment: Download WMI Code Creator from Microsoft downloads center: [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572][1]. Generate the code from the WMI Code creator to be executed on the remote machine and then try.

Comment: I had read that post long time back before asking question and used same only. But no luck.

Comment: when i run below wql code in wmi code creator.

strComputer = "machineName" 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select FileSize from CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = 'C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit'",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "CIM_DataFile instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "FileSize: " & objItem.FileSize
Next

It will return 0x80041017 which is error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing, but since your query is syntactically correct and uses the correct field and object names, I assume it is because you pass the string "C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit" as `DSADatabaseFile`. That would by correct for "typical" use inside C#, like when using the `Path` class, or such, but not here.

You need to pass the filename with two backslashes to WMI. Since, however, C# requires to already, you need to effectively pass four:

```
 getDatabaseFileSize("C:\\\\Windows\\\\NTDS\\\\ntds.dit", machine)
```

or using a verbatim string literal:

```
 getDatabaseFileSize(@"C:\\Windows\\NTDS\\ntds.dit", machine);
```

**Update** Here is a complete example:

```
// Compile with: csc foo.cs /r:System.Management.dll

using System;
using System.Management;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private int getDatabaseFileSize(string DSADatabaseFile, string machineName)
        {
            string scope = @"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2";
            string query = string.Format("Select FileSize from CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = '{0}'", DSADatabaseFile);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject mobj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Size : " + mobj["FileSize"]);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();

            // These work
            p.getDatabaseFileSize("C:/boot.ini", ".");
            p.getDatabaseFileSize(@"C:\\boot.ini", ".");
            p.getDatabaseFileSize("C:\\\\boot.ini", ".");

            // These fail
            try {
                p.getDatabaseFileSize("C:\\boot.ini", ".");
            } catch (ManagementException ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", ex.ErrorCode);
            }
            try {
                p.getDatabaseFileSize(@"C:\boot.ini", ".");
            } catch (ManagementException ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", ex.ErrorCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with:

The (expected) output is:

```
File Size : 313
File Size : 313
Failed: InvalidQuery.
Failed: InvalidQuery.
```

**Update** There seems to be a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972232/21567) question already (mentioning the need for `\\\\` instead of `\\`).

Comment: No luck, I have tried all.

C:\\Windows\\NTDS\\ntds.dit and C:\\\\Windows\\\\NTDS\\\\ntds.dit also. Same error.

Comment: Well, it worked for me when using your code (both the error and then the fix using the doubled double-backslashes). You may also want to try using a single (forward) slash instead of (any) backslashes as directory separator. E.g. `C:/Windows/ntds/ntds.dit` works for me as well.

Comment: I am surprised that it work for you, but I tried all kind of slash, its not working for me.

I get this error often working with different wmi classes.

Comment: Well "invalid query", just means that an invalid query was passed. Could be a couple of things. I typically get that, when referencing unknown properties or classes, or messing up the syntax (missing spaces between keywords, unclosed quotes, whatever).

Comment: thanks for information

i run the test for different files
 getDatabaseFileSize("C:/Windows/bootstat.dat", machineName);
            getDatabaseFileSize(@"C:\Windows\bootstat.dat", machineName);
            getDatabaseFileSize(@"C:\\Windows\\bootstat.dat", machineName);
            getDatabaseFileSize("C:\\\\Windows\\\\bootstat.dat", machineName);

same error.

Comment: hey thanks christian, it worked. I was changing variable value at runtime from quickwatch. But that did not reflected somehow.

But when i replace it and use it worked.

Thanks